# Not being able to dualboot Windows 11/Linux

Tags: linux, windows, boot, bios

I come with the question about dual booting Windows 11 on 1st SSD and Ubuntu on 2nd SSD.

After different tries with different scenarios, I'm still not abel to run installation of Linux on second drive. I will describe what I've tried, getting information from other posts:

My PC motherboard - ASUS TUF GAMING B550-PLUS WIFI II 1st SSD with Windows 11 already installed, 2nd SSD mounted My system BIOS is set for UEFI

General scenario I'm starting from every time:

create bootable USB with rufus 4.3 using parameters: official ubuntu 22.04 .iso partitioning - MBR / BIOS or UEFI formating - FAT32
After restart I jump in to BIOS, but I cannot see anything except Windows Boot Manager (even my second SSD), I've changed CSM to UEFI and Legacy, proceed to save and restart. I can see now all of my devices in boot manager, when I choose USB Flash, PC boots in to" GRUB _" test on the lefty of the screen and nothing happens after 20 min

2nd try:

Repeating same as in 1st try, but changing Secure Boot for "Other OS" save & restart, resolves in blinking cursor on the left of the screen, nothing happens

3rd try:

Repeating same as in 1st try, deleting PK Key from secure Boot - secure boot is disabled (checked in msinfo32 in windows), same white cursor blinks on the left of the screen and nothing happens

At this point I have no other clue what I could do to run Linux installation on my PC, did you encounter something like this? Is there anything I can do with it?

Maybe some valid information is I use Windows with WSL2 in general, but wanted to have additional Linux on second drive, as sometimes I want to use clear Linux

Thank you for help in advance!

Comment: Microsoft Hyper-V, Citrix XenServer and VMware ESXi all support GPU pass-through mode. If you have 2 GPUs, you could perhaps use a Linux VM on Windows and pass it one GPU.

Comment: I have often found a way around this by physically disconnecting the Windows drive, then install Linux on it's own drive (thus getting it's own EFI partition), then reconnect the Windows after it is completed and known to be working. Use BIOS menu to select which OS to boot, after that is working you could manipulate grub to handle it all for you if you wish.

Comment: Don't enable CSM. It would only cause more trouble and confusion, especially if you want to be able to boot to Windows via grub. If you can't see the Ubuntu installation drive on your UEFI boot menu, fix the drive. Ubuntu ISO should be hybrid ISO, which means it's best to write it to a USB drive with "dd mode". AFAIK Secure Boot setting does not prevent non-signed executable for being enumerated. (You'd just get an error when you choose to boot it.) Besides, IIRC Ubuntu has Microsoft-signed bootloaders (or shim, at least), so you shouldn't need to mess with anything.

Answer (score 0):

**Preliminary note**: You already messed with too much stuff you shouldn't have and may neet to reset UEFI and repair Windows 11 or, probably better, reinstall it before attempting to dual-boot (more about that later).

UEFI mode and Secure Boot enabled are requirements for Windows 11 so a) don't disable Secure Boot and b) do NOT enable CSM/Legacy. Neither have anything to do with your problem whatsoever.

And this is what you need to know/consider moving forward:

- If you plan to dual-boot in machines with drive modes currently unsupported or only partially supported in Linux - Intel RST and other UEFI RAID features - which tend to be the default for factory installed Windows then you have to change to **AHCI** and install Windows (in an already installed Windows you would need to follow instructions to install AHCI support).
- When dual-booting with any Windows 8.x or newer, disabling its Fast Startup feature is a must.
- UEFI updates are often necessary for stable Linux installation.
- Although most current Linux distros allow installation in MBR ('msdos') drives for UEFI mode (and conversely GPT for BIOS/Legay mode with an additional unformatted partition), Windows doesn't! So make sure all your drives are GPT (not required for new, blank, drives).

Assuming the aforementioned conditions there can only be one relatively rare problem with the graphics when booting the installation media / live session in a motherboard like yours (will be addressed later).

At this point you should create a proper installation media. As always, make sure the ISO itself isn't corrupt (if downloaded by BitTorrent (recommended), in a known good drive, it's automatically verified during and after the download).

This *can* be a problem:

> create bootable USB with rufus 4.3 using parameters: official ubuntu 22.04 .iso partitioning - MBR / BIOS or UEFI

The thing is it should work, and the Rufus developer is adamant it does, both for BIOS or UEFI but many users reported it doesn't. As such, for Rufus and your machine, it's better to choose the other option - UEFI/GPT -, use the `dd`mode or another tool. A couple of recommendations...

- [Balena Etcher](https://etcher.balena.io/) - Simple, does the same as Rufus without options/features. It's just load the ISO, select the target, "burn".
- [Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html) - Creates multi-boot with many ISOs (as much as there's space for) and supports anything that's "bootable", Linux Windows, others. Simply download the Windows installer, run it, select the drive to install and done. Now just copy the ISOs to the drive, no additional tools required.

Now assuming *all* the aforementioned conditions you should be able to successfully boot an Ubuntu live session and install Ubuntu. If you notice graphical 'glitches' then try again and select the option with "safe graphics" then, later, when installing make sure to select the option to install additional drivers, 3rd party, codecs, etc. This is almost mandatory for Nvidia graphics, Intel and AMD don't need user installed drivers.

Comment: _"the Rufus developer is adamant it does, both for BIOS or UEFI"_ That's because the Rufus developer (myself) does tend to __test__ these things, and has not seen any issue. Especially, I re-tested `ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso` (which I assume is what OP uses) with Rufus 4.3 and had no problem booting on a BIOS legacy system (an old Dell machine) as well as a Secure Boot enabled UEFI system (an intel NUC). _"but many users reported it doesn't"_  __Where?!?__ Because they sure as heck haven't bothered to e-mail me or open an issue at https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/issues...

Comment: @Akeo There are questions at AskUbuntu, many treads at Ubuntu Forums, Mint, Manjaro, etc.

Comment: Ah, yes, the good old _"Why don't you spend 24 hours a day in every major Linux user forums to look for issues (whereas I already spend plenty of time checking reddit, superuser and other locations) instead of expecting that people who think they found a problem that appears to pertain with a specific utility will actually bother to report it to the creator of the utility using one of the many links that are plastered all over the software (such as __direct__ e-mail, GitHub tracker, etc.)?"_ Silly me... Oh and I very much check AskUbuntu for Rufus related issues.